# Flutter confetti issue

Tags: flutter, dart

At the end of liquid swipe, when the Let's start button is clicked, I would like confetti animation to play for 3-4 seconds and then present the user with App home screen. When I run this code, I don't get any error  and neither does confetti animation play. On clicking Let's start, the home screen of app is displayed.

Update: 25/11/2022 I was able to run confetti successfully and have also added a listener to capture current state. I would like the confetti to run for 3 seconds and the screen to be routed to home screen using

```
                    AppRoute.pushReplacement(context, const MyApp());
```

```
import 'package:a/main.dart';
import 'package:a/provider/home_provider.dart';
import 'package:a/provider/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:a/ui/app_route.dart';
import 'package:a/ui/widget/styled_text.dart';
import 'package:a/utils/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:liquid_swipe/liquid_swipe.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher_string.dart';
import 'package:confetti/confetti.dart';

class OnBoarding extends StatefulWidget {
  const OnBoarding({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OnBoardingState createState() => _OnBoardingState();
}

class _OnBoardingState extends State<OnBoarding> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final pages = [
      IntroductionContainer(
        heading:
            'a',
        body:
            "b",
        color: Color(0xff3937bf),
        animation: 'assets/lottie/a.json',
      ),
      IntroductionContainer(
        heading:
            'c?',
        body:
            "d",
        color: Colors.pink,
        animation: 'assets/lottie/h.json',
      ),
      IntroductionContainer(
        heading:
            'e',
        body:
            "f",
        color: Color(0xff27b56f),
        animation: 'assets/lottie/g.json',
      ),
      IntroductionContainer(
        showAction: true,
        heading: 'Ready ?',
        body:
            "aaaa",
        
        color: Color(0xfff46d37),
      ),
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      body: LiquidSwipe(
        pages: pages,
        enableSideReveal: true,
        // enableSlideIcon: true,
        enableLoop: false,

        positionSlideIcon: 0,
        slideIconWidget: const Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back_ios,
          size: 30,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IntroductionContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  IntroductionContainer(
      {required this.heading,
      required this.body,
      required this.color,
      this.showAction = false,
      this.animation,
      Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  final String heading;
  final String body;
  final Color color;
  final bool showAction;
  final String? animation;

  @override
  State<IntroductionContainer> createState() => _IntroductionContainerState();
}

class _IntroductionContainerState extends State<IntroductionContainer> {
//Adding Confetti controller and other variables
  bool isPlaying = false;

  final _controller = ConfettiController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 2));

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
//Listen to states playing, stopped
    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = _controller.state == ConfettiControllerState.playing;
      });
      if (_controller.state == ConfettiControllerState.stopped) {
        AppRoute.pushReplacement(context, const MyApp());
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: widget.color,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              widget.heading,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 25,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            if (widget.animation != null)
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                child: Lottie.asset(
                  widget.animation!,
                  height: 400,
                  width: 400,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            if (widget.animation == null)
              InkWell(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                  child: Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 200,
                        width: 200,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/a-2.png',
                          height: 120,
                          width: 120,
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Icon(
                        Icons.play_circle,
                        size: 60,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () async {
                  var url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaaaaa';
                  if (await canLaunchUrlString(url)) {
                    launchUrlString(url);
                  }
                },
              ),
            Text(
              widget.body,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),

            ConfettiWidget(
              confettiController: _controller,
              //set direction
              //blastDirectionality: BlastDirectionality.explosive,
              // to set direction of confetti upwards
              blastDirection: -3.14 / 2,
              //minBlastForce: 10,
              //maxBlastForce: 100,
              //colors: const [Colors.deepPurple, Colors.black, Colors.yellow],
              numberOfParticles: 20,
              gravity: 0.5,
              emissionFrequency: 0.3,
              //  - Path to create oval particles
              createParticlePath: (size) {
                final path = Path();
                path.addOval(Rect.fromCircle(
                  center: Offset.zero,
                  radius: 4,
                ));
                return path;
              },

              //  Path to create star confetti

              /// A custom Path to paint stars.
              //Path drawStar(Size size) {
              // Method to convert degree to radians
              //double degToRad(double deg) => deg * (pi / 180.0);
              //const numberOfPoints = 5;
              //final halfWidth = size.width / 2;
              //final externalRadius = halfWidth;
              //final internalRadius = halfWidth / 2.5;
              //final degreesPerStep = degToRad(360 / numberOfPoints);
              //final halfDegreesPerStep = degreesPerStep / 2;
              //final path = Path();
              //final fullAngle = degToRad(360);
              //path.moveTo(size.width, halfWidth);
              //for (double step = 0; step < fullAngle; step += degreesPerStep) {
              //path.lineTo(halfWidth + externalRadius * cos(step),
              //  halfWidth + externalRadius * sin(step));
              //path.lineTo(halfWidth + internalRadius * cos(step + halfDegreesPerStep),
              //  halfWidth + internalRadius * sin(step + halfDegreesPerStep));
              // }
              //path.close();
              //return path;
              //}
            ),
            //ConfettiWidget(

            const SizedBox(height: 50),
            if (widget.showAction)
              ButtonTheme(
                height: 50,
                minWidth: 150,
                child: MaterialButton(
                    // borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                    color: AppColors.blue,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    child: const Text(
                      'Let\'s Go',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
//Calling Confetti controller and adding confetti widget
                      if (isPlaying) {
                        _controller.stop();
                        //await Duration(seconds: 4);
                        AppRoute.pushReplacement(context, const MyApp());
                      } else {
                        _controller.play();
                        //await Duration(seconds: 1);
                      }

                      //await Duration(seconds: 1);

                      //confettiController: confettiController,
//                      shouldLoop: false,
                      // blastDirectionality: BlastDirectionality.explosive,
                      //);

                      //var userProvider =
                      //Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);
                      //userProvider.updateTrial();
                      // HomeProvider.setAppLaunched();
                      //AppRoute.pushReplacement(context, const MyApp());
                      //},
                    }),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

At the end of liquid swipe, when the Let's start button is clicked, I would like confetti animation to play for 3-4 seconds and then present the user with App home screen. When I run this code, I don't get any error  and neither does confetti animation play. On clicking Let's start, the home screen of app is displayed.
PS: I am new to flutter

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you put the `ConfettiWidget` inside of the `onPressed` callback of your button.

You should add it in your `Column` like any other widget and display the confetti by triggering the controller you pass to your `ConfettiWidget` inside the `onPressed` callback with the help of `_controller.play()`

Comment: Thanks. Where should I add the ConfettiWidget? I do not see a column within the above code. I am learning and new to flutter.

Comment: You do have a `Column` with multiples text and button in it.
If you provide me with a zapp.run sample of your code, I will make you an interactive example

Comment: I was able to run the confetti animation, just stuck at not being able to transition to main screen after the animation completes in 2-3 seconds. Can you take a look at the code please? Sorry I could not create the zap run as it was buggy for me.